# Azure B2C access token missing tenantId

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I read the [B2C access token documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens), and I noticed that the tenantId claim (tid) is not in the list. This is different from the normal [Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) access token claims.

I need to have this claim on the B2C access token (using B2C policies) for the token cache to work but I don`t know how to include it on the payload.

How can I include TenantId (tid) claim on a B2C access token payload?

Comment: AAD includes it since in a multi-tenant app the user might log in with any tenant. In B2C they will login against your B2C tenant. Thus there is no need for a tenant id claim. Why does the token cache need it?

Comment: @juunas The token cache requires it to create the unique cache key for the logged user. The key is the combination of ObjectIdentifier and TenantId. The reason for this combination is because MSAL representes a user by `IAccount` and since the ObjectIdentifier would be the same if you use your MSA account in several apps, the tenantId would be key to distinguish these accounts.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AAD-B2C-specifics#known-issue-with-azure-b2c

Comment: @TiagoBrenck have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Not a good solution, but a workaround though. I added a key on the app config that holds `tid` value.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can really help you. But I have moved to use Custom Policies, where it's possible to have far more control on what is returned to the user.

In my example, I am returning the tenantId like this:

```
File: SignUpOrSignin.xml
```

```xml
<RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" PartnerClaimType="emails" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="picture" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="correlationId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Context:CorrelationId}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
```

Azure B2C custom policies are far more complicated than we usually would expect, but in the other hand, there are much more opportunies to customize the authentication flow.